# How do I open/close this panel in IB?

Tags: xcode

Apologizing in advance for a noob question (I'm new to xcode) - I recently opened up this left panel by accident on IB.

*How do I close and reopen this panel?  (What is it called BTW)?*

It doesn't appear to be a navigator or an inspector!?!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This button will toggle open & close the **Document Outline** panel:

[image]